# How Can I Add More Languages to Stopwords in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I'm using NLTK with stopwords to detect the language of a document using the method described by Alejandro Nolla at http://blog.alejandronolla.com/2013/05/15/detecting-text-language-with-python-and-nltk/ , and it works reasonably well.

I'm also working with some additional languages not included in the NLTK stopwords package, such as Czech and Romanian, and they get false matches as other languages. These are the languages in stopwords:

['danish', 'dutch', 'english', 'finnish', 'french', 'german', 'hungarian', 'italian', 'norwegian', 'portuguese', 'russian', 'spanish', 'swedish', 'turkish']

How can I expand the list of languages supported by NLTK? Are there other stopword lists available that I can add? Is there a documented method I can use to create an add my own stopword lists?

Comment: In case anyone will find it useful, the extra stopword lists I was using with my now-defunct project are freely available on Github here: https://github.com/Xangis/extra-stopwords

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googling for "Romanian stopwords" brings up a good number of resources.

If you want to do this yourself, you simply need to find words which are common in all genres of text. (The article you link to has a rather poor explanation of what stop words are.) Good candidates are articles, particles (if your language has them, and they occur in isolation), conjunctions, pronouns, and some types of adverbs.

[*Automatically Building a Stopword List for an Information Retrieval System* (Rachel Tsz-Wai Lo, Ben He, Iadh Ounis; University of Glasgow, 2008)](http://terrierteam.dcs.gla.ac.uk/publications/rtlo_DIRpaper.pdf) (PDF) documents an automatic method for finding stop words. I have not looked at the method or its results.

https://github.com/berkmancenter/mediacloud/blob/master/script/mediawords_generate_stopwords.pl seems to have an implementation. (The comment has other names than the article; not sure what's up with that.)

Comment: Tangentially, Section 2 of http://www.enroweb.com/IMG/pdf/StopwordList_preprint.pdf has a nice one-paragraph historical summary.

Comment: Thank you, that gets the second part of the question. Any idea how to go about editing/changing what's in NLTK?

Comment: If it's https://github.com/mhawthorne/antonym/tree/master/lib/nltk-data/corpora/stopwords it's just a simple text file, one word per line, file name is the language. (That's somebody's clone, I guess, but too lazy to hunt down the master. Besides, the README indicates it was copied from another project.)

Comment: To clarify, all I had to do was copy a file named "romanian" containing one word per line into my NLTK data directory and NLTK picked it up and started using it. In my case it was ~/nltk_data/corpora/stopwords/